# Is it bad to use a variable from outside the observable pipe within an operator?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Is using a variable from outside an observable within an operator considered a (significantly) bad practice?

```
createObservableExample1(parameter1: string, obs$: Observable<string>): Observable<string> {
    return obs$.pipe(
      map( x => {
        const returnValue = `${parameter1}, ${x}`;
        return returnValue;
      })
    );
}
```

I understand you can do something like this:

```
createObservableExample2(parameter1: string, obs$: Observable<string>): Observable<string> {
        return combineLatest([
          of(parameter1),
          obs$  
        ]).pipe(
            map( (x, y) => {
                const returnValue = `${x}, ${y}`;
                return returnValue;
            })
        );
    }
```

But is it worth it?

Does this just come down to accessing variables from outside the scope of anonymous function? Would this force the context of the enclosing method to exist for longer than it should? I remember a code tool I used to use for C# complaining about something similar to this. I have found somewhat related topics by searching for, "anonymous functions and closures", but as of yet, nothing really discussing the scenario explained above.

I ask because I have been creating some relatively complex observables that have enormous operator chains, and constantly adding the needed variables, using **combineLatest** and **of**, from the parent scope can make the code even harder to follow.

Comment: I think this is a question of personal prefference but in my opinion I have no problem with the first variant where the value is encloused in the function closure. It is possible to create chains with almost no side-effects but that makes every chain overcomplicated while the practical benefit is almost non-existent. It's more likely you'll have a bug because your chain is complicated (and hard to understand) than from side-effects or from accessing `this` in your chain.

Answer (score 0):

When I teach Reactive programming to neophytes, I try to make them grasp : Do not break the reactivity by having uneccessary side effects :

- no input that from a state (for example using a class or instance property
- no storing outside value.

There is none of these red flags in your example. Your function is pure & idempotent with both implementation, go with what ever you like and if possible be consistant within your code base !